# does osCommerce have an API?

Tags: api, oscommerce

We work on a lot of integration projects and a customer has a legacy ecommerce site and have asked us to integrate product information, orders and inventory with another platform.

Does osCommerce have an API that can be used for this, or will we need to build our own web services based wrapper for the dB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not that I know of.

I think you'd need to find one online (never heard of one) or build one yourself.

Comment: thanks - I don't think there is one but I thought it best to ask the experts :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bizmovi.com
It seems come with demo site.

> API written in PHP for osCommerce, adaptable any client platforms which allow to rapidly mash-up existing osCommerce with iOS, Android, Windows Phone, Blackberry, WebOS, Symbian, Bada, etc.